# set number to class for json objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am returning JSON to display a history of comments starting with the most recent.

I'm trying to set a number to a class in a list item tag.

For example, I'm trying to achieve this:

```
<li class="1">comments</li>
<li class="2">comments</li>
<li class="3">comments</li>
// and so on
```

I am using the following:

```
$.post('process/searchComments.php', {histuid: histuid}, function(data)
{
  var obj = JSON.parse(data);
  $('#transactionHistory').empty();
  var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function (item)
  {
    var number = 0;
    number++;

    return '<li class="'+number+'">item.comment</li>';
  }).join('');
  $('#transactionHistory').html(htmlToInsert);
});
```

But I'm returning this:

```
<li class="1">comments</li>
<li class="1">comments</li>
<li class="1">comments</li>
// and so on
```

How can I alter my code so that it shows the consecutive numbers in the classes?

Comment: For what reason are you trying to do this? I ask as incremental id/class attributes are generally an anti-pattern and the problem can be solved in much better ways

Comment: Basically, I have been asked to highlight the most recent comment.  I figured I could just set the class using JQuery, then use CSS to highlight the class with 1.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Are the comments appended in date order? Ie, is the first one the one which needs to be highlighted?

Comment: The comments are returned with the most recent being the first.

Comment: Ok, in that case you can use CSS. I've edited the answer below with another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because you define `number` and set it to `0` in every iteration.

To fix the problem you can use the second argument of the `map()` handler function, which is the index of the current element within the set you're iterating through. You can concatenate that to your string instead:

```js
var data = '["lorem","ipsum","dolor","sit"]';
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function(value, i) {
  return '<li class="' + (i + 1) + '">item.comment</li>';
});
$('#transactionHistory').html(htmlToInsert);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="transactionHistory"></ul>
```

Note that you don't need to call `empty()` as `html()` overwrites the values in the element anyway.

> I have been asked to highlight the most recent comment. I figured I could just set the class using JQuery, then use CSS to highlight the class with 1. The comments are returned with the most recent being the first

In this case you can just append the HTML and use CSS to select the first one. This way you don't need to worry about any extraneous classes on the content you append:

```js
var data = '["lorem","ipsum","dolor","sit"]';
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var htmlToInsert = obj.map(v => `<li>${v}</li>`);
$('#transactionHistory').html(htmlToInsert);
```

```css
ul li:first-child {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="transactionHistory"></ul>
```

Comment: Wow.  So simple.  I was over-thinking it.  Such a simple fix.  You, sir, are a genius.  I didn't have to make a change to the htmlToInsert part.  All I did was add the CSS, and it worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It´s happening because you **define number and set it to 0 in every iteration**.
Try it:

```
var number = 0;
$.post('process/searchComments.php', {histuid: histuid}, function(data)
{
   var obj = JSON.parse(data);
   $('#transactionHistory').empty();
   var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function (item)
   {  
      number++;
   return '<li class="'+number+'">item.comment</li>';
 }).join('');
$('#transactionHistory').html(htmlToInsert);
});
```